# Trouble setting up OpenVPN

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Hey I've been trying to connect to the OpenVPN I've set up on my router via Ubuntu but it keeps timing out.  I tested it on a Windows device and it connects with no problems, so I know it has to be something I'm overlooking in Network Manager.  I checked my routers system logs and the error displayed is:

```
Jan  1 16:18:01 openvpn[6203]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]192.168.1.139:43908

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]192.168.1.139:43908, sid=362f6bd8 58b312d1

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=0

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 TLS: Username/Password authentication succeeded for username 'masterofnone' [CN SET]

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 WARNING: 'dev-type' is used inconsistently, local='dev-type tap', remote='dev-type tun'

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1592', remote='link-mtu 1540'

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 WARNING: 'tun-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='tun-mtu 1532', remote='tun-mtu 1500'

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 WARNING: 'auth' is used inconsistently, local='auth SHA1', remote='auth [null-digest]'

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key

Jan  1 16:18:02 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication

Jan  1 16:18:03 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

Jan  1 16:18:03 openvpn[6203]: 192.168.1.139:43908 [masterofnone] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]192.168.1.139:43908

Jan  1 16:18:03 openvpn[6203]: masterofnone/192.168.1.139:43908 MULTI: no dynamic or static remote --ifconfig address is available for 
masterofnone/192.168.1.139:43908

Jan  1 16:18:03 openvpn[6203]: masterofnone/192.168.1.139:43908 Connection reset, restarting [0]

Jan  1 16:18:03 openvpn[6203]: masterofnone/192.168.1.139:43908 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I just looked at a log from a successful connection to my server.  The lines are basically the same until the line after Peer Connection Initiated.  The line in my log after that reads `[redacted connecting device name]/::ffff:67.142.235.252 OPTIONS IMPORT: reading client specific options from: ccd/[redacted]` So I think you were OK until then.  Did you set the option that requires each connecting device to have an entry in the `ccd` directory?  The line after that in mine is `[redacted connecting device name]/::ffff:67.142.235.252 MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.2 -> [redacted]/::ffff:67.142.235.252`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Could you tell me how I might go about accessing the ccd directory?  When looking at Advanced Settings all I see is:  http://imgur.com/a/E8iQB

Comment: The setting is in server.conf and consists of the lines `client-config-dir ccd` and `ccd-exclusive`.  The directory itself is found in `/etc/openvpn`.  If those lines are commented out in your server.conf this is not the problem.  I don't know anything about that GUI for openvpn, I set mine up via command line.  So you probably have no way to get at that config file.  See my next comment.

Comment: Some comments about stuff I saw in the GUI: I use a TUN interface.  Not familiar with TAP.  I use UDP protocol, not TCP.  Does your client config match this in every respect? There are boxes to check in the Network Manager for these non-default configs (found by clicking the Advanced button).

Comment: Yes it matches up exactly: http://imgur.com/a/Kis6c .  I had originally set it up as UDP but it wouldn't connect to the Windows computer or my Ubuntu laptop.   Thanks a lot for your help I'm going to keep trying to figure out what's wrong.